# How to add await inside Promise?

Tags: javascript, axios

Is it possible to add Await inside new promise ?

Originally, I don't need to put a await before making any request to the server. But one day, the server requires every request to have a token before sending out.

Let's take an example of the code

```
export const countries = (data: IData) => {
  const countryRequests = getRequests(data)
  const countryResponse = countryRequests?.reduce((countryResponse, request) => {
    const countryResponses = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      instance
        .post(`/country`, request)
        .then(data => {
          resolve(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          reject(err)
        })
    })

    return [...countryResponse, countryResponses]
  }, [])


  return countryResponse
}
```

new code( putting async into the callback of promise):

```
export const countries = (data: IData) => {
  const countryRequests = getRequests(data)
  const countryResponse = countryRequests?.reduce((countryResponse, request) => {
    const countryResponses = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { //add async here
    await addAccessToken() // add header into token before sending the requests
      instance
        .post(`/country`, request)
        .then(data => {
          resolve(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          reject(err)
        })
    })

    return [...countryResponse, countryResponses]
  }, [])


  return countryResponse
}
```

addToken function:

```
export const addAccessToken = async () => {
  const accessToken = await instance.get<IAccessToken>(
    '/access_token'
  )
  const { access_token } = accessToken.data
  instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Be ${access_token}`
}
```

But then I got a error below

**Promise executor functions should not be async.(no-async-promise-executor)**

How can I get rid of the error?

-------------- new changes---------

```
export const countries = async (data: IData) => {
  const countryRequests = getRequests(data)
  await addAccessToken()

  const countryResponse = countryRequests?.reduce((countryResponse, request) => {
    const countryResponses = instance
      .post(`/country`, request)  //------- May I ask, if it is successful call, then this will autmactically equvlanet to calling resolve (data) in my previosu code? 
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
      })
    return [...countryResponse, countryResponses]
  }, [])

 
  return countryResponse
}
```

added new prmosie.all part

```
const countryResponses = countries(data)

    //set content for api 1
    Promise.all([...countryResponses])
      .then(values => {
        const countryResponsesResult = values.map((value, _index) => {
          return value.data.result ? value.data.result : []
        })
       
        //Set content for api 1
        props.setProjection({
          kind: 'success',
          payload: {
            data: countryResponsesResult,
          },
        })
      })
      .catch(_error => {
        //Set content for api 1
        props.setProjection({
          kind: 'fail',
          payload: {
            error: new Error(_error.message),
          },
        })
      })
```

Comment: `new Promise(async (resolve, reject)` is definitely an anti-pattern - the fact that you're attempting to await something inside the executor, suggests you already have a Promise to use ... so, no need to create a `new Promise`

Comment: You can replace that entire promise with ```const countryResponses = instance.post('/country', request)```. It has exactly the same effect, since `instance.post` already returns a promise.

Comment: async/await and then/catch are two different approaches that should be differentiated and not mixed, you can find more explanations online that compare the two

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you give an example? I just want the to execute instance.post only after I run  addAccessToken, so it ensure that token is added, and importantly,  no error message promping

Comment: I think the second comment by deceze explains it adequately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @deceze mentioned, instance already returns a promise for you so no need to return your own promise.

Just

```
export const countries = async (data: IData) => {

await addAccessToken()
const countryResponses = await instance.post(`/country`, request)
//your code//
```

If you don't want to use `await` and use promises and `then` instead you should have something like the below(promise chaining):

```
export const countries = (data: IData) => {

addAccessToken()
     .then((data)=>{
        const countryResponses = instance.post(`/country`, 
        request)
     })
     .then(//your code//)
```

Comment: thanks for commenting, may i ask if it is possible to keep my resolve, reject function without new Promise? The reason I want them is because somewhere in code, I have using Promise.all , I need it to notify it

Comment: @AeLeung - this isn't a "comment", it's an answer

Comment: Thank you for editing the post. I have made a change to my code according to your suggestions, but I still have a problem in my new code, could you confirm my concern there? commented in the code

Comment: What do you mean to "notify" the Promise.all? There is no point in using resolve/reject, when the asynchronous code completes the promise will resolve automatically (that's the whole point).

Comment: @AeLeung Regarding your question in your edited code Yes, if the awaited statement succeeds this means that the promise was resolved, if rejected the catch will run

Comment: I see, what struggles me is that somewhere in my code used Promise.all( Promise1,Promise2,Promise3....  ), in which I want to use resolve() to notfiy Promise.all function, after the Promise was succeed. @Marios

Comment: Where is this code? Do you have `await` before `Promise.all()` ? You should also change that code wherever you have it and remove the `.then` and do it with `await`

Comment: I immediatedly found out there is a problem with the Promise.all , I added new edit , could you give me some advise of what wrong with it ? @Marios

Comment: I tried to add await before Promise.all , but still get a error, So no so sure how to fix it according to your suggestion, especially the .then part, would you mind showing examples? @Marios

Comment: What is the error you get???

Comment: TS2461: Type 'Promise<any>' is not an array type. @Marios  , right next to Promise.all

Comment: @Marios In addition, to your second approach, may I ask if it is possible to enable caches in addAccessToken()? Since this appraoch will force to request token every time to call api, it will be way more faster if it can prevent calling again, as token can last for 30 mins

Comment: I think your problem lies in the reduce. Why do you need reduce? You can use forEach.

`const countryResponse = [];
try{
 countryRequests?.forEach(( request) => { const response = await instance.post('/country', request) }
countryResponse.push(response)
}
catch(err)=>console.log(err)`

Comment: That's a good question. The reason I used reduce is that I want to embed the initate array in the code, so I dont have to write countryResponse = []; People say this seems to be a bad code style to initial a global variable, then assign value into it in some function.  @Marios

Comment: I finally write a solution that works, I'll post it down there. But I dont know how I can avoid duplicated token request, in which token only expired after 30 mins.

Comment: @Marios Maybe, the question is extending too much. But still I would like to thanks all and appreciate your time in answering the question

Comment: @Marios if possible, could you also upvote my question either, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I found this work.

```
export const countries = (data: IData)=> {
  const countryRequests  = getRequests(data)
  const countryResponse  = countryRequests?.reduce((countryResponse, request) => {
    // return promise
    const countryResponses  = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      addAccessToken().then(()=>{
        instance
          .post(`/country`, request)
          .then(data => {
            // change the returned propmise state into resolved
            resolve(data)
          })
          .catch(err => {
            reject(err)
          })
      })

    })
  //return the whole set of simlationCalls promise. When all promise is resolved, promise all will be notified and excute whatever it needs to execute
    return [...countryResponse, countryResponses]
  }, [])

  return countryResponse
}
```